# Get Elements by Class, Filter By Parent Class

Tags: javascript, html

My table includes several hundred rows, some with `class="include"` and some with `class="exclude"`. My Javascript successfully ticks all the boxes in my table. However, I actually want to select only the boxes within a `tr class='include'`

**Here is my HTML:**

```
<tr class='include'><td><input class='checkboxplay' type='checkbox' name='checkbox[]' value='myvalue'></td></tr>

<tr class='exclude'><td><input class='checkboxplay' type='checkbox' name='checkbox[]' value='myvalue'></td></tr>
```

**And here is my Javascript:** (selects all boxes)

```
var items = document.getElementsByClassName('checkboxplay');
      for(var i=0; i<items.length; i++){
        if(items[i].type=='checkbox')
          items[i].checked=true;
      }
```

I thought something like this would work to filter by `class="include"`, but it doesn't work at all. That is, it does not tick any of the boxes. Any suggestions?

```
var items = document.getElementsByClassName('include').getElementsByClassName('checkboxplay');
      for(var i=0; i<items.length; i++){
        if(items[i].type=='checkbox')
          items[i].checked=true;
      }
```

Comment: `var items = document.querySelectorAll(".include .checkboxplay")`

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but that doesn't seem to select any boxes either.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`document.querySelectorAll()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll) with the [descendant combinator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Descendant_selectors) ('.include .checkboxplay') to select all children of `.include` that have the class `.checkboxplay`:

```js
var includeCheckbox = document.querySelectorAll('.include .checkboxplay');

// just for demo - will add a red outline arround the selected checkbox
includeCheckbox.forEach((el) => el.style.outline = '1px solid red');
```

```html
<table>
  <tr class='include'>
    <td><input class='checkboxplay' type='checkbox' name='checkbox[]' value='myvalue'></td>
  </tr>

  <tr class='exclude'>
    <td><input class='checkboxplay' type='checkbox' name='checkbox[]' value='myvalue'></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 1):

Remember javascript selectors are same as CSS one.
So you target `.include .checkboxplay` for styling in css.
Hence, for javascript its `document.querySelectorAll(".include .checkboxplay")`